# WAMP changed port but the application link wont update from localhost to localhost:8080

Tags: wamp, port

WAMP changed **port 80 to 8080** in **Apache > httpd.conf** but the application link won't update from localhost to localhost:8080

And so I have to type :8080 when starting the application **over and over again...**

**The Question is:**
Is there any way to make wamp application link to localhost and localhost/phpMyAdmin to  localhost:8080 and  localhost:8080/phpMyAdmin so I don't have to type this all the time ?

Thx :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit c:/wamp/wampmanager.tpl file so the WAMP menu points to `localhost:81`.

Find `http://localhost` and change it to `htttp://localhost:81`
also, if you think something else has already grabbed port 80, that is why its not working..,then,

Run wampmanager->Apache->Service->Test port 80

This will launch a command window and tell you what is using port 80.

Whatever it is will need to be re-configured to use another port or for example if its IIS and you dont use IIS it should be un-installed.

Comment: My port 80 is used by Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0 

I dont even know what a hell is this and how to uninstall it :)

Comment: Its common, usually a service called Web Deployment Tool Installation MsDepSvc, is behind this event. Just stop it and disable to free the port 80 or use 'net stop msdepsvc'

Comment: Works great. Thx Shivanshu Srivastava! ;>